# Why I get executor refused connection?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have something strange in the execution of my code:

When I execute the following line:

```
sourceList = joinLabelrdd_df.select("x").collect()
```

I get the following execption. Noting I have enough memory and cpus.

```
 19/07/14 11:22:34 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 5 on 172.16.140.68: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
19/07/14 11:22:34 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20190714111835-0000/5 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 137)
```

This error cause another exception:

```
19/07/14 11:22:41 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 113.1 in stage 9.0 (TID 2154, 172.16.140.113, executor 9): FetchFailed(null, shuffleId=0, mapId=-1, reduceId=113, message=
org.apache.spark.shuffle.MetadataFetchFailedException: Missing an output location for shuffle 0
```

Comment: Looks like joinLabelrdd  is huge and failed during repartition(1) and also you’re doing collect. Try to save into file without using collect and verify this is not because of collect.

Comment: did you submit with stand-alone or yarn?

Comment: @DennisLi yarn. I have 4 nodes with 30cpu per nodes and 8gb per cpu.

Comment: check spark-ui while running , and make sure there is not any container broken. repartition(1) is likely to account for problem if your data is large

Comment: @DennisLi my data is around 3gb.

Comment: check this article https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/ based on this you can tune your spark parameter and this one [Don’t collect large RDDs](https://umbertogriffo.gitbooks.io/apache-spark-best-practices-and-tuning/content/dont_collect_large_rdds.html)